# how do you handle multiple account services during creation?

Tags: meteor

At the moment I have a custom signin with google button based on:
https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-customizing-login

in accounts.js I do something like this to get the google accounts info:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user){

    var accessToken = user.services.google.accessToken,
    result,profile;

    result = Meteor.http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo", {
        params: {
            access_token: accessToken
        }
    });

   ....
```

service.js

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: "google"
});

ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: "google",
    clientId: "...",
    secret: "..."
});
```

at the moment it only handles google, but I also want to add accounts-password and fb. How can check onCreateUser what service the service was and whether it was custom.

Update:

```
if (user.services.google !== undefined){
  //google service
}
if (user.services.facebook !== undefined){
  //facebook service
}
```

Comment: Problem : "Meteor account system is currently not supporting the ability to link different external services account(such as Twitter, Facebook) to the same Meteor user. "

Please take a look at this pull request, it should help you:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1133

Comment: well its not so much that I want link multiple accounts to one user account, rather I'm trying to create custom login without using {{loginButton}} so the user creates an account using google OR custom OR fb. The problem is that on the server side I need to know which service they used so I can access the appropriate access token.

Answer (score 0):

`Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user){`

Do `console.log(options)` and `console.log(user)`. Do this with regular/facebook/twitter accounts and you will see the difference.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, but accounts.js is on the server side, it doesn't output to the browser console, it does however show [object object] on the terminal.